# How can I get a reference to the worksheet an event was generated in?

Tags: excel, vba

In a worksheet I can attach code to an event like so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
  ' .. code here
End Sub
```

**How can I get a reference to the worksheet the event was generated in?**

I want to have a 100% secure way, so I don't have to worry about code breaking when the name worksheet changes etc.

`ActiveSheet` is not correct because it is not guaranteed that any sheet is active upon (re)calculate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use caller:

```
Application.Caller.Worksheet.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Codename property:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Debug.Print Me.CodeName
End Sub
```

By default it's the same name as the worksheet, but you can change it in the Properties Window of the VBE - it's the Name property.  The user can't change it.   (Copying a sheet adds a number to the name, e.g., Sheet1 becomes Sheet11.

You can also use it in the workbook-level event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
If Sh.CodeName = "TheSheetICareAbout" Then
Debug.Print Sh.Name
End If
End Sub
```

It's hard to be more helpful as you don't say how you'll use the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Some more information on code names:

http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-vba-sheet-names.htm